# Can a planet's magnetic field be used to generate power?

Tags: science-based, electromagnetism

According to my relatively shaky understanding of science, moving a conductor through a magnetic field generates power. And the magnetic field of the earth rotates with the earth. So, if an orbiting object (say, a satellite) orbited in the direction opposite the earth's rotation, and was travelling roughly along the magnetic equator, could that satellite generate power from the magnetic field?

Comment: I believe this is off-topic here. How is it about building fictional worlds? It's a simple engineering issue, that's all. also, it was already answered on our sister site: [Can the Earth's magnetic field be used to generate electricity?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/65082/104551)

Comment: A good question, but as Molot says, check out that link to Physics.SE. I'm voting to close this as off-topic.

Comment: If framed out in a world building narrative this would be fine and on-topic without question and I don't find the narrative entirely necessary personally.  That said you may well get a better answer from Physics.  If you are looking at how to use it in an imaginary setting update the question and it should stay or get re-opened.  Welcome to the site John.  Check out the [help] for more details on how to write good questions and answers.

Comment: @James I disagree. Narrative wouldn't make this on topic. At best, it would make it story-based.

Comment: @Mołot I think that as per the logic given in the answers to [this meta post](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/4074/627), the question could still be on-topic.

Comment: This is not the earth's EMF, but man-made EMFs: http://newatlas.com/scavenging-ambient-electromagnetic-energy/19163/

Comment: Also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_harvesting

Comment: There's some similar question here: http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/5013/under-what-circumstances-would-it-be-possible-to-harvest-aurora-for-either-energ

Comment: @HDE there must be a border somewhere. I hope that adding "because I want this in my world" isn't a magic key to making anything on topic? Because if it is, nothing would be off topic anymore.